# Order by count in many to many polymorphic relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Let's take the example from the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations it's easy to get all `posts` with their `tags` count doing `Post::withCount('tags')->get()`.

But how to get all `tags` with their usage count ? To have them ordered by most used / less used.

If I do `Tag::withCount(['video', 'post'])->get()` I will have 2 attributes `videos_count` and `posts_count`. In my case I would like a unique `taggables_count` that will be the sum of the two. In a perfect world by adding a subselect querying the pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more searching I find out there is no way to do it with only in one query due to the fact that in `mysql` we can't do a select on subselet results. So doing `Tag::withCount(['videos', 'posts'])` and trying to sum in the query the `videos_count` and `posts_count` will not work. My best approach was to create a scope that read results in the pivot table :

```
public function scopeWithTaggablesCount($query) {
    if (is_null($query->getQuery()->columns)) {
        $query->select($query->getQuery()->from . '.*');
    }

    $query->selectSub(function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('count(*)')
            ->from('taggables')
            ->whereColumn('taggables.tag_id', 'tags.id');
    }, 'taggables_count');

    return $query;
}
```

To use it :

```
$tags = Tag::withTaggablesCount()->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

So now we have a `taggables_count` for each tag and it can be used to `order by`. Hope it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply doing the call you already did, which is `Tag::withCount(['video', 'post'])->get()`, and add this to your Tag model:

```
// Tag.php
class Tag
{
  ...
  // Create an attribute that can be called using 'taggables_count'
  public function getTaggablesCountAttribute()
  {
    return $this->videos_count + $this->posts_count;
  }
  ...
}
```

and then in your loop (or however you use the items in the collection):

```
@foreach($tags as $tag)
  {{ $tag->taggables_count }}
@endforeach
```

This setup requires you to get the Tags with the `withCount['video', 'post']` though. If you do not, you will likely get `0`in return for `$tag->taggables_count`.

If you're really concerned about speed, you would have to create the query manually and do the addition in there.